# Understanding of practice usage of ASP.NET 5 Middleware

Tags: .net, middleware, asp.net-core

This great article explains things about [ASP.NET 5 Middleware, Or Where Has My HttpModule Gone?](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone)

But it is still unclear about when and why we have to use **ASP.NET 5 Middleware**.

Can anyone explain  it and provide real life examples of its usage?

Comment: My article can't be that great if it failed to answer those points clearly enough for you ;)

Comment: @MikeBrind  Your article is great. I am just refering to it :)

Comment: I just wrote an article that may help you as it has concrete examples of middleware components, and a link to real world Ruby middleware too http://keyoti.com/blog/asp-net-v5web-apivnextowin-a-beginners-primer-part-1/

Comment: @JimW Thank you!  I will read it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "discuss this {BLOG}"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. You would create a middleware to get a hold of a request and decide:

- Whether you want to process it and pass it to next middleware.
- Whether you want to process it, generate a response and cut the request lifecyle there.

You can also have a middleware to act on the responses only (e.g. a middleware who does the compression).

Most of the middlewares are to provide cross cutting functionality such as routing, authentication, compression, error handling. A few real world examples on these:

- [ASP.NET 5 Routing Middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Routing/RouterMiddleware.cs)
- [ASP.NET 5 Authentication Middlewares](https://github.com/aspnet/Security)
- [ASP.NET 5 Error Handler Middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.cs)

One confusion could be around framworks here such as MVC, SignalR, etc.. Previously in Katana world, each framework was creating each own middleware to hook into the system. With ASP.NET 5, this is a little different.  In order for a framework to process requests, you can hook into the routing middleware by providing a special handler. For example, here is the [MVC 6 route handler](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/MvcRouteHandler.cs). When you look at the biuilder extensions, you will see that [MVC actually uses the routing middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/27191114538c92ac1901bf18cb20124102a99892/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/BuilderExtensions.cs#L60).