# Register handlers for application events in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

If I wanted to handle application events in my ASP.NET app, I would register a handler in my `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ ... }
```

`Global.asax` has been removed from ASP.NET 5. How do I handle such events now?

Comment: From what I could find, I believe this is all done in the `startup.cs` file in ASP.NET 5. http://wildermuth.com/2015/3/2/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_2_-_Startup

Comment: @Drew Kennedy - heh heh you were faster and even provided the same link

Comment: @Tanis83 Yup! I would have provided it as an answer, but really it was just a guess. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to run some logic for each request in ASP.NET 5 is through Middlewares. Here is a sample middleware:

```
public class FooMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public FooMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // this will run per each request
        // do your stuff and call next middleware inside the chain.

        return _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

You can then register this in your `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

See here for [more information on Middlewares in ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721895/463785).

For any application start level invocations, see [application startup documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#application-startup).

Comment: Would I use middleware for all other events as well? `Application_Start`, `Application_AuthenteicateRequest`, `Session_Start`, etc...?

Comment: The middleware's Invoke method will be invoked per each request depending on where you middleware sits inside the chain. For application start, there are several places inside the `Startup` method where you can tab in like `Startup` ctor, `ConfigureServices` method and `Configure` method.

Comment: have a look here for more info on `Startup` class: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#application-startup

Comment: @tugberk Does that mean imply that startup class in ASP.Net MVC Project replace global file in ASP.Net Web Form ?

Answer (score -2):

ASP.NET Apps can live without global.asax.

**HTTPModule** is alternative to global.asax.

Read more [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19389/HTTP-Handlers-and-HTTP-Modules-in-ASPNET.htm).